# Why can't we reduce visibility while method overriding (specially public to default)

Tags: java, overriding, return-type

This is a very basic concept that we can't reduce the visibility of a method while overriding. But I want to understand why?

```
class Parent{
  public void getData(){
   System.out.println("Parent GetData")
  }
}
class Child{
  void getData(){
   System.out.println("Parent GetData")
  }
}
public class OverridingDemo{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  Parent p = new Child();
  p.getData(); // Error
 }
}
```

Here we have changed the return type to default which allows accessibility to same package. Then why is it not allowed to change the return type to default?
I do understand that if it was private or protected then in that case it cant be accessed but why not for default? 
 Yes, there are already a lot of threads available but I wasn't able to understand the concept clearly.

Comment: If you have something of type `Parent`, then you expect it to have a method `getData()` with public visibility. If `Child` reduces the visibility of said method, what should happen in this situation: `Parent parent = new Child(); parent.getData();`?

Comment: @Turing85 Thanks for the reply. That's what I asked. I understand if the visibility is reduced to private or protected then other class wont be able to access but what if visibility is reduced to default and the classes are in same package?

Comment: What if they are not? The public access modifier guarantees accessibility from everywhere. You have always to consider the "worst case" .

Comment: @Turing85 Thank you. :) 
I got it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's about type safety and polimorphism.

It can't be done, precisely because the extending classes can be polimorphically passed everywhere the extended class can. Thus, the caller of extended class (say `com.yadvendra.vehicles.Car` with public method `int speed()`) calls the public method of the class. But the instance variable holding the class can be either the extended class (`Car`), or the extending class (say `RaceCar`). Because of polymorphism, the caller of `Car.speed()` should be able to call `RaceCar.speed()` without knowing the exact type - the compiler just needs to make sure that `Car` is substituble to `RaceCar`. That's polymorphism.

The caller of `Car.speed()` has the right to call `.speed()` method, since it's public. Have you lowered the visibility of `RaceCar.speed()`, then the caller would receive `RaceCar` of which `speed()` is `protected` (or `default`). And it would appear that the caller can't call the method. So the compiler doesn't allow that.

However, the fact that you try to change the visibility of the method on the extending class points to a deeper issue. It would seem that you want to extend the class, but not its interface (since you'd like to hide some of the methods). That seems like a strong reason to believe that your `Child` class should probably not extended `Parent` (because it wouldn't be substituble for `Parent` anyway).

Comment: The question is specifically for public to default return type. I mentioned the same in question that I do understand that if it was private or protected then it would create a problem but why not default?
Thanks for the reply. :)

Comment: @Yadvendra the problem is the same whether it's `private` or default - *someone* won't be able to call it despite it being public in the *declared* type.

Comment: Your argumentation is somewhat flawed. Java (and many other type-safe OO-languages) deeply reflect the Liskov substition principle, but type-safe languages came first and on a more concrete level. Liskov describes the substition on a more abstract level, talking about types  and their exchangability. Type-safety is neither a guarantee nor required to realize Liskov substition principle, so while they support each other, they are independent from each other.

Comment: @Turing85 Correct.

Answer (score 1):

> I do understand that if it was private or protected then in that case it cant be accessed but why not for default?

The default access is no different. It's a relative comparison: reducing the scope to **any** more restrictive scope is not permitted, simply because it breaks the contract of the superclass, as explained in comments.

**Side note**: you seem to understand that `protected` is less permissive than the `default`/`package-private` scope. This is not true. `protected` is `package-private` and more.

Comment: Thank you for the side note. I actually thought that protected is less permissive.
Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Users of API are only supposed to know the Parent class. How can you explained them that they can nkt use certain method now, just because one if the implementation if the Parent class has reduced the visibility in child class?